# In bash how to echo on the next line into a file?

Tags: bash

I try to retrieve the 1st column of the file **results** and put this column on the file named **results2**, but the problem is my script only write the **last** line of **results**:

```
for line in $(cat results | cut -d" " -f1);
do echo -e "$line">results2;
done
```

Comment: Note you are doing it right, only that you are truncating the file every time with `>`. That's why you end up having just the last line. Instead, use `>>`.

Comment: awk '{print $1}' results > results2 can what you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do what you want in the shell like this:

```
while read -r col1 rest
do 
    printf '%s\n' "$col1"
done < results > results2
```

...but it'd make a lot more sense to just do this:

```
cut -d' ' -f1 results > results2
```

The problem with your script is that you're using `>` inside the loop, which truncates the file and reopens it for writing every iteration. You can get around this by redirecting the whole loop to the file but as I've shown, the best method is just to redirect the output of `cut`.

To read lines in the shell, use a `while read` loop; [don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor). However, bear in mind that the shell isn't designed to do this task efficiently, whereas that's exactly what the standard tools such as `cut` are there for.